# Im getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' Whats the correct syntax

Tags: php, string

Im getting a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Whats the correct way to order my quotes for the code below.

```
echo "<td>".anchor("users/delUser/".$users[$i]->userid.")</td>";
```

Comment: Why did you mark it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

The close parenthesis should be before the `.`:

```
echo "<td>".anchor("users/delUser/".$users[$i]->userid)."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your last `."` in the wrong place. You need this:

```
echo "<td>".anchor("users/delUser/".$users[$i]->userid)."</td>";
```